# Single VPS, multiple IPs - different iptables rules based on IP

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

I currently have a VPS with just 1 IP address and I want to buy another IP and do the following:

- have one public IP with incoming requests allowed only on port 7777 (UDP)
- have a Mysql server running there
- have the other IP that only I will have access to (so, private) which will have opened http and ssh ports (http is for accessing phpMyAdmin and a small control panel which will have access to the mentioned mysql server)

I have enough knowledge to write the iptables rules, I just don't know how to write them for multiple IPs.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to have a separate IP for that? You can have it on the same IP and set up the firewall rules to only allow yourself access from specific whitelisted IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for different IP addresses are not affecting each other. You first write the rules for one of the addresses and then those for the other one.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d 1.2.3.4 -p udp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d 1.2.3.5 -p tcp --dport   22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d 1.2.3.5 -p tcp --dport   80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d 1.2.3.5 -p tcp --dport  443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```